# remove_section in a plugin

Tags: plugins

I tried to remove a section of a child theme in a plugin with the following code:

$wp_customize->remove_section('rb_aboutyou_section');

but nothing has changed.

Comment: are you sure that you remove it after the definition ? don't forget that the `functions.php` of the child theme is called before parent's one

Comment: Please mention the specific theme. Is it really a section and have you got the id right? Please also try `remove_control`.

Comment: I am actually working on responsiveboat theme which is already a child theme of zerif-lite. I also tried to remove_control, but I am not really sure how I can find the right id to remove control. For section id, I am pretty sure that it is the right one.